# Too slow archlinux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, arch-linux

I have both *ubuntu* (latest - 15.04 with fresh updates) and *archlinux* (latest) but when I boot in arch I have a problem: everything is slow as a snail.

On archlinux the flashplugin **FREEZES** the whole system - even cursor does not move when something is playing from both `chromium` and `firefox` browsers. I've enabled hardware acceleration in `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg`, my nvidia proprietary driver (352 version) works amazingly good in meaning of acceleration and opengl stuff. But this is not the only problem - when I try to compile something on archlinux, with `make` or `make -j9` (fits my configuration fully) it does it **extremely slow** a little-little project compiles like 15 minutes.

On ubuntu I have no any issues with flash plugin everywhere. Also, exactly this project that compiles ages on archlinux I compile on ubuntu less than one minute. This problem is not only happens to compile or flash player but even responsiveness in the UI: on ubuntu it is working pretty good everywhere but on archlinux I have `awesome-wm` installed only without even any login managers - it freezes sometimes too. I don't even know where too look the problem.

**My PC:**

```
Intel Core i7 2600 (always turbo-boosted)
DDR3 16GB RAM
NVIDIA 550GTX
```

**Compilers (both are slow, but clang is 1-2 minute slower than g++):**

```
g++ (GCC) 5.1.0
clang version 3.6.1 (tags/RELEASE_361/final)
```

Comment: Does `htop` show any CPU usage on idle Arch? Also `iotop` for disk usage? `dmesg` for any sort of kernel errors?

Comment: @grawity anything is okay in `htop` and `iotop`. No any errors in `dmesg` found. I've found some similiar behaviour of some people on the internet but these posts were made in 2013 and they were not solved.

Comment: are you using the official kernel?

Comment: Yes, I use official kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but the problem is gone. What I did since posting this question is:

1. fixed cpu - changed thermal compound, cleaned the whole pc. I did this because I found that my processor is very hot. I also noticed, when it is hot - it is much slower.
2. updated the distro every day. So this may be a fix in the kernel or something.. Now everything is even better than in ubuntu.